# JSBeautifier shortcut

Tags: script, javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

This userscript adds a shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) to beautify the selected JavaScript code using the same engine that also runs [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org).

You can [find the source on GitHub](https://github.com/ThiefMaster/SO-UserScripts) (feel free to fork, improve and send a pull request) or just [install it right away](https://github.com/ThiefMaster/SO-UserScripts/raw/master/StackOverflow_JS_Beautifier.user.js).

#### ChangeLog:

- 1.0: Initial release
- 1.1: Works in Chrome
- 1.2: Fixed beautifier URL